# Is looping and blocking on recv the best way to handle a long-lived process in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a set of long-lived process with really expensive setup that I want to push into a bank of worker processes for doing their work parallel. Each worker is different, building from different parts of our database. I will occasionally shut down the workers and rebuild them, say every 4 hours or so.

The python examples I've seen for the multiprocessing module seem to be all-the-same, short-lived processes that do one thing once and then exit.

Here's a sample that I came up with for distributing the work to a bank of all-different, long-lived workers.

Is this on track, or there a better way to do this?

```
class Worker(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)  # ...or super
        self.parent_side, self.pipe = Pipe()

    def do_super_slow_initialization(self):
        print 'all work and no play makes Jack a dull boy'

    def run(self):
        self.do_super_slow_initialization()

        while True:
            message = self.pipe.recv()

            if not message:
                break

            self.pipe.send({'message': message,
                            'pid': os.getpid(),
                            'ppid': os.getppid()
                            })

        self.pipe.close()


def main():
    print '+++ (parent)', os.getpid(), os.getppid()

    workers = [Worker() for _ in xrange(10)]

    # start the workers
    for w in workers:
        w.start()

    # a bunch of messages to get through
    for x in xrange(10):

        # send message to each worker
        for y, w in enumerate(workers):
            w.parent_side.send('work%s_%s' % (x, y))

        # get the results
        for w in workers:
            print w.parent_side.recv()

    # shut down
    for w in workers:
        w.parent_side.send(None)
        w.join()
```

Comment: This seems the work that a [`Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) should do, but without context I have no idea if this fits your needs or not. [Style note: you can get rid of the `while True: + break` pattern with `for message in iter(self.pipe.recv, None):`.]

Comment: @Bakuriu: Considering that he needs a `do_super_slow_initialization()` on each process, but not for each job, using a `Pool` may be very difficult.

Comment: Anyway, there's nothing particularly bad about this design. Having 10 processes blocked on `recv` calls is close enough to free as makes no difference. It might complicate your error handling—if the child processes fail unexpectedly, your parent needs to deal with that in some way. But otherwise, it seems reasonable.

Comment: @abarnert you can provide an `initializer` argument to `Pool`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Exactly. I got hung up on initializing the pool, since all the processes are based on different queries. I thought about hacking Pool and just shoving my Processes in ;) but decided to take the high road. I'll take another look at initializer and see if that will work. Thanks for the tip on iter... that does seem much more elegant.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks! Fortunately, in *this* case I can just suppress and log errors and return an empty dict, so that simplifies things. But that was the kind of concern I was worried about.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Yes, an `initializer` can't be used to, e.g., set local variables, so it's not always trivial to swap in. It's usually worth refactoring the code so the jobs can be self-contained functions that know how to access initial data appropriately, but not always. And, even when it is worth doing, it's still a bit of effort.